# Checking if BIDS is installed using Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I trying to find out if their is a way to check and see if BIDS is installed on a server using Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

While there's no direct way to look for this using Management Studio, you can check for the existence of devenv.exe on the SQL Server by issuing:

```
xp_cmdshell N'dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"'
```

:)